# How do I sync Couchbase-Lite Android with CouchDB?

Tags: android, couchdb, couchbase-lite

The problem: During a push I get a "Bad Request" error and some sort of authentication error even though it gets a positive response.

I have almost no experience with CouchDB or Couchbase, but from what I understand you'd usually sync Couchbase-Lite with Couchbase Sync Gateway, but since the latter uses CouchDB's replication protocol you can still use CouchDB as long as you don't use "Channels". Replication with CouchDB is mentioned [here](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/replication/index.html#filtered_pull_couchdb). I would prefer not to use Couchbase Sync and Couchbase Server since this is a small experimental project for now, I don't need channels and my server has nowhere near enough resources.

I'm using CBL-Android 0.0.0-501 (the most recent one right now I think, already tried 1.0.3) and CouchDB 1.5.0.

This is called in the onCreate method of my main activity on Android:

```
void minimalPushTest() throws IOException, CouchbaseLiteException {
    String databaseName = "cblpushtest";
    String couchDbUrl = "http://192.168.4.11:5984";
    String userName = "testuser";
    String userPw = "testpw";

    // initialize database
    Manager manager = new Manager(new AndroidContext(this), Manager.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
    Database database = manager.getDatabase(databaseName);
    Document document = database.createDocument();
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    data.put("somekey", "sometext");
    document.putProperties(data);

    // start push replication
    Replication replication = database.createPushReplication(new URL(couchDbUrl));
    replication.setContinuous(false);
    replication.setAuthenticator(new BasicAuthenticator(userName, userPw));
    replication.start();
}
```

This is what CouchDB says about "/_session" for user "testuser":

```
{"ok":true,"name":"testuser","roles":["testing"]}
```

...and for "/cblpushtest/_security":

```
{"admins":{"names":[],"roles":[]},"members":{"names":["testuser"],"roles":["testing"]}}
```

Here is the logcat output in Android Studio:

```
03-15 23:15:14.999  27429-27429/ W/Sync﹕ [fireTrigger()] => START
03-15 23:15:15.109  27429-27429/ W/Sync﹕ [fireTrigger()] => GO_ONLINE
03-15 23:15:15.199  27429-27546/ E/Sync﹕ com.couchbase.lite.replicator.ReplicationInternal$4@429cbb20 checkSessionAtPath() response: {ok=true, userCtx={name=testuser, roles=[testing]}, info={authentication_db=_users, authentication_handlers=[oauth, cookie, default], authenticated=default}}
03-15 23:15:15.309  27429-27546/ W/Sync﹕ com.couchbase.lite.replicator.ReplicationInternal$9@4291cab0: error getting remote checkpoint
03-15 23:15:15.309  27429-27546/ E/Sync﹕ com.couchbase.lite.replicator.PusherInternal@429c1758: Progress: set error = org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Bad Request
03-15 23:15:15.309  27429-27546/ W/Sync﹕ [fireTrigger()] => STOP_GRACEFUL
03-15 23:15:15.314  27429-27562/ W/Sync﹕ [fireTrigger()] => WAITING_FOR_CHANGES
03-15 23:15:15.314  27429-27562/ W/Sync﹕ [fireTrigger()] => STOP_IMMEDIATE
```

Somehow an "ok=true" response is shown as an error.

And this is couch.log (clocks aren't seem synchronized, but these are the relevant outputs):

```
[Sun, 15 Mar 2015 22:14:32 GMT] [info] [<0.29026.2>] 192.168.4.61 - - GET /_session 200
[Sun, 15 Mar 2015 22:14:32 GMT] [info] [<0.29024.2>] 192.168.4.61 - - GET /_local/3e7d908842481392245906438560f235e9d3138f 400
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out: the database url needs to point to the actual database, not just to the CouchDB root. I thought I had tested that earlier, but I think at that time I still had authentication issues so I had dismissed that solution too early.

The correct line for couchDbUrl is therefore

```
String couchDbUrl = "http://192.168.4.11:5984/"+databaseName;
```

..and it probably doesn't even need to have the same name, but I didn't check. Anyway, the data gets pushed now.

Comment: Hi @Netcob, have you tried the latest releases of couchbase-lite and couchDB together? I couldn't find any documentation that can confirm that you can use them together. if you could work with them together.. have you found any limitations? tnx!